# Can I get myself a drink from the galley in an ITA airways flight?

Tags: airlines, aircraft

I am going to be on an ITA Airways flight, and I wonder, can I get myself a drink from the galley? This is my first ITA Airways flight by the way, so I don't know.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/187824/is-it-acceptable-for-airplane-passengers-to-help-themselves-to-drinks-in-the-gal

Comment: the best way to find this out is to ask on the flight when they first come around with the trolley, or later when you ring your call bell to ask for an extra drink. Galley access varies from airline to airline, flight to flight, and even with seat class.

Comment: Just press the call button, then request the drink. Unless it was clearly announced that there are snacks available in the galleys are passengers are welcome, which is very rare.

Comment: @NeanDerThal as a crew member, do you prefer when passengers come to the galley (outside of busy times) or if they use the device button? As a passenger I would think the former, but maybe I have it wrong. It may vary a lot from one airline/culture to another, though.

Comment: @jcaron we prefer when passengers press the call button. Galley is the only place where crew might have some "private" time, we do not like to have that ruined.

Answer (score 2):

I can’t find any information on the ITA Airways website stating that a self-service arrange exists, except maybe in business class on long haul flights.

However:

- There is nearly always a snack or meal service, sometimes 2 or even three depending on the duration the flight.
- On long-haul flights you can usually go to the galley during quiet times and ask for a drink. Don’t do it when they are busy (mostly during the time around the meals).
- If you see snacks and drinks arranged in the galley in a way that makes it look like you can serve yourself, go ahead. Otherwise just ask politely.
- You can also use the call button at your seat, but stretching your legs is never a bad idea.

Details may vary a lot based on the type of flight (short or long, intercontinental or not) and of course service class.